# TYPO3 Extbase: update record with logging of changes

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-extensions

When I update an object with an Extbase repository (e.g. in a cronjob or in the frontend) like this...

```
$myRepository->update($myObject);
```

and afterwards I use button "Display change history / Un-do" for this record in TYPO3 BE, I don't see any history. I only see a history when editing the object in TYPO3 BE.

How can I enable the history?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short version: you can't, because the history is for changes done in the backend interface only.

Longer version: you sort of, kind of can, but that would involve quite a bit of custom code in your repository which would do one of two things:

1. Override the `update` method on your repository and from it, fire `DataHandler` methods to update the record - then use the persistence session to mark your object as clean so Extbase doesn't try to persist it again. Updates via `DataHandler` will write the history.
2. Also override the `update` method but write the history records manually instead of allowing `DataHandler` to do it.

The first solution is very complex to handle. The second one means you have to implement a bit of (duplicated) code and likely won't cause all the usual hooks to trigger in TYPO3 (which is usually fine but does sometimes cause trouble with third party extensions). If you are forced to do this, I would choose the second solution. But I would first of all consider if perhaps the need to have BE-specific history for anonymous (no BE user) editing that's bordering on abuse of what that undo history was *also* intended for: tracing *who* made a change.

Comment: Also the relationships of sub properties like images or something else (M:N, 1:N, etc) must be done manualy with using of the DataHandler. More of the DataHandler can be found here: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Typo3CoreEngine/Database/Index.html